# MySQL: Unrecognised statement type. (Near Revoke)

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Using mySql on phpMyAdmin, I am trying to create a new users, and edit their permissions, firstly by granting access to everything, then removing only the specifics. When I try and do this, I always get an error message under 'Revoke'. I tried the auto create feature and then copied the sql this generated yet still an error under the 'Revoke'.

```
CREATE USER 'x'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '123';
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'x'@'localhost';
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* FROM 'x'@'localhost';
```

Error: 'Unrecognised statement type. (near REVOKE)'

Could anyone provide an answer to this?
Thanks

Comment: Answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53898874/2178980

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE USER 'x'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '123';
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'x'@'localhost';
REVOKE DROP ON DB.* FROM x'@'localhost';
```

Should be correct since your `revoke` statement was wrong

MySQL official [link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/revoke.html) on `REVOKE`