# REVOKE command not recognised by phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I am attempting to create a new user for my database with `read` permissions and then remove the users `DROP` permission.

I have tried the code seen below, however, it does not seem to work. A red squiggly line is placed under the command `REVOKE`, with the error message :

> Unrecognised statement type. (near `REVOKE`)

I don't have a clue what's wrong?

```
CREATE USER Dave@'localhost'  IDENTIFIED BY 'password' ;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DB.* TO 'Dave'@'localhost';
REVOKE DROP ON DB.* TO 'Dave'@'localhost';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Comment: Probably unrelated but it's `REVOKE ... FROM` not `TO`.

Comment: @stickybit Yeah that actually worked. Dumb moment from me there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You `REWORK` synatax is wrong.

As par [the mysql docs on `REVOKE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/revoke.html) :

```
REVOKE
    priv_type [(column_list)]
      [, priv_type [(column_list)]] ...
    ON [object_type] priv_level
    FROM user_or_role [, user_or_role] ...
```

So you  want :

```
REVOKE DROP ON DB.* FROM Dave'@'localhost';
```